# Did The Prophecy become true?

Tags: harry-potter, prophecy

The prophecy said that Harry Potter would kill Voldemort. But, Voldemort died because of his own Killing Curse backfired on himself. Does The Prophecy justify it?

Comment: The prophecy said "Neither shall live while the other survives." That means either Harry had to kill Voldemort or Voldemort had to kill Harry -- they could not co-exist in the world. Seeing as Voldemort was killed, the prophecy was fulfilled. Now I'm going from memory here, so if I've forgotten some other part of the prophecy that is worded differently, please do correct me, by all means. :)

Comment: Also, I think it's important to stress that Voldemort was the one who gave credence to the prophecy; others did not. So was the prophecy *really* important? No, not really. It mattered only because Voldemort decided to believe in it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The prophecy never said the chosen one was going to kill the Dark Lord, it simply stated he had the power to do so.

> "The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches ... born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies ... and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not ... and either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives ... the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies ..."
>   —Prophecy made to Albus Dumbledore by Sybill Trelawney

Comment: its prophecy they almost always need a sophistic answer

Comment: "...and either **must die** at the hand of the other..." This tells us that one MUST kill the other.

Comment: Your first statement is wrong. The prophecy absolutely states that the chosen one must either die or kill Voldy.

Comment: Harry did die at Voldemort's hands.

Answer (score 7):

### There are a number of ways in which the prophecy could be interpreted to have been completed.

> "The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches ... born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies ... and the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not ... **and either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives** ... the one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies ..."
>   —Prophecy made to Albus Dumbledore by Sybill Trelawney

**The most obvious way this clause could be fulfilled would be for Harry to kill Voldemort.**
Arguably, this did not happen, as the killing curse that ended Voldemort's life was cast by Voldemort himself.

Just as arguably, it did happen.  Voldemort died because Harry chose to challenge him and put his will into 'reclaiming' the Elder Wand, which is why the wand refused to kill him and rebounded. (Note that the Elder Wand earlier had the opportunity to refuse to kill him back in the wood, and didn't, indicating that some measure of Harry's will matters in this.  If he hadn't wanted to spell to rebound, Voldemort probably would have lived)

It's like tying someone to the train tracks and then claiming that you didn't kill them.  *Technically*, the train killed them.  But you're still going to be tried for murder, and you're still fulfilling the prophecy.

**The prophecy doesn't say that Harry has to kill Voldemort.  One of them has to kill the other.**
The prophecy could just as easily be fulfilled if Voldemort killed Harry.  Hm... What happened back in the Forbidden Forest?  True, Harry came back, but it could still be argued that Voldemort killed him.

**The other what?**
The exact wording is "and either must die at the hand of the other".  Normally it would be assumed that "the other" is referring to "either" as what it is the other to.  But prophecies love twisting grammar to their own ends.  "The other" could instead be referring to the subject of the previous sentence: "... **he** will have power the Dark Lord knows not."  *He* as in Harry.  Making "the other" Voldemort.  Meaning that the sentence could be read as "and either must die at the hands of *Voldemort*.  Which very certainly happened.

All of these reasonings are flimsy in their own ways.  But prophecies thrive of flimsy reasoning.  These aren't any more ridiculous than MacDuff being "no man of woman born" or soldiers holding branches counting as "Great Birnam wood to high Dunsinane hill"

Comment: "prophecies thrive of flimsy reasoning" is the real answer here

Answer (score 1):

The prophecy didn't say that Harry Potter would kill Voldemort. It merely stated that someone with power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches. It doesn't say whether he will be successful.

As Voldemort didn't die by Harry's hand, that didn't happen.

One could argue that the prophecy came true when Voldemort killed Harry in the forest, but Dumbledore emphasizes that Voldemort failed to kill Harry.

> “He killed me with your wand.”
>
> “He failed to kill you with my wand,” Dumbledore corrected Harry. “I think we can agree you are not dead."

One could argue that baby Harry killed Voldemort, be Voldemort also wasn't really dead. So it seems the prophecy is not fulfilled, at least not between Harry and Voldemort. There may be some other Dark Lord and some potential vanquisher, so the prophecy may be fulfilled at another time.

This doesn't contradict the books. In Half-Blood Prince, Dumbledore says

> "Do you think that every prophecy in the Hall of Prophecy has been fulfilled?"

implying that not every prophecy is fulfilled. He goes on to say

> only because Voldemort made a grave error, and acted on Professor Trelawney's words ... Voldemort himself created his worst enemy

So Dumbledore says that Voldemort made the classical mistake of believing a prophecy and by trying to avoid it he causes it to come true. (The classical story is about [Oedipus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus))

Answer (score 0):

The prophecy had already been fulfilled in the first war.

> "... he will have a power the Dark Lord knows not"

That was Lily's protection which Voldemort hadn't been aware of.

So Harry had already "vanquished" the Dark Lord, but no one predicted that Voldemort would have Horcruxes.

The rest of the Harry Potter story (after baby Harry caused Voldemort's downfall) involves Dumbledore moving things around like a chess piece to bring about Voldemort's ultimate downfall.

This one had little to do with prophecy.

If Voldemort hadn't been obsessed with prophecies (which Dumbledore was well aware of) , he would have seen Harry as the half-trained, non-threat of a teenager that the latter was.

Then, maybe he would have ordered Harry's death, but not obsessed over killing him, which allowed Dumbledore to lure him into a trap.

By obsessing over Harry, Voldemort stole Harry's blood and used it to create a new body.

That had the effect of making it impossible for Voldemort to kill Harry, because Lily's blood protection was now in Voldemort's veins. When Dumbledore heard of this, he got a brief gleam of triumph in his eyes. He then briefly said something about Voldemort not fully knowing how Old/Blood magic worked.

Unfortunately , none of this was fully explained in the last book. Instead of going with this plot. It was dropped in favor of some fresh convoluted plot about wands, which was invented for the final book, so Rowling could give a a GOT ending.

I love the series but book 7 was just a rushed, half-finished mess, with a convoluted plot thrown in to wrap things up.

So many questions went unanswered. So many plots were left to the side.

Who even heard of "Beetle the Bard" before book 7?

I saw the writing on the wall, before I was even halfway through the book after that. And I was right. A new plot was brought in to wrap things up just as I feared.

I really wish people would stop doing the authors' work by filling in the plotholes FOR them, but fans will be fans I guess.

And all any author has to say is "yeah, that was TOTALLY what I was going for all that time" LOLZ.

Comment: There are a few important factors you raise there, I will address a couple. 1. It's a children's story, it doesn't have to perfectly hang together, it just has to be a great adventure. 2. Blood magic goes to some very dark places for a children's book and she was probably right to kill that idea off rather than building on it too much.